# Needed - Visual Studio Custom Build Actions To Minify JS and CSS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compression, minify, combres

I've been using [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/) in my applications to compress, combine and minify my javascript and css at run time. This works extremely well and satisfies [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) perfectly.

Now I'm rethinking the whole process for performance reasons, and I'm more so thinking about doing all of this at build time instead of run time.

I'm hoping that I can get a little advice on how to do this without too much hassle. Is there an existing tool (similar to Combres) that can do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally used [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) to do my bundling, but have since moved over to [Bundler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Bundler). [Bundler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Bundler) allows me to wire everything up nicely in a sexy build file (powershell) with relative ease. I've personally moved away from Visual Studio Build events, and started running the builds in a stand alone environment. This helps me with things like [Github](https://github.com/) to [Team City](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) Continuous Integration (CI).

Here's what your build file "could" look like. *(note might not fully run, this is untested)*

---

### build.ps1

```
# Set up varriables for build script
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
$BundlerDir = "$directorypath\build_tools\bundler\"
$AppRoot = "$directorypath\SomeApp.Web\"   
$ScriptsDir = "scripts\"                                   
$CssDir = "css\"                  

# Run Bundler to Combine and Minify
&($BundlerDir + "node.exe") ( $BundlerDir + "bundler.js") ($AppRoot +$CssDir) ($AppRoot + $ScriptsDir)

# Everything else...
#    Clean the bins
#    Build the projects
#    Run the tests
```

Answer (score 13):

Meet Chirpy

[image]

Chirpy Mashes, minifies, and validates your javascript, stylesheet, and dotless files.

Chirpy is chippy. Use Google Closure Tools or YUI Compressor for .Net to minify and mash all of your precious assets. It's easy, it's flexible, and it's automatic.

[More info here](http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/22/visual-studio-add-in-for-dotless-js-and-css-files/) or on the [CodePlex site](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 4):

The MSBuild Community Tasks Project has a JSCompress task.  Check out the project here:  http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

Here's another resource on how to actually implement this task:  http://www.justise.com/2007/04/20/javascript-and-css-compression-in-msbuild/

Comment: Now I don't have a "build machine" per se, but rather just my development machine.  Will these suggestions still work?

Comment: PS, I've very new to custom build stuff... in fact, I've never done it.

Comment: Yes, the build script is run every time you compile your project no matter the configuration.  I was new to it too not to long ago.  Its kind of a set it and forget it kind of thing. So I feel like I'm new to it if I ever have to make a change.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take at look at ajaxtoolkit they have 2 tasks for compression of JS.